# Detecting if NSString contains chinese characters

Tags: iphone, objective-c, nsstring

I have an `UISearchBar`, and I want my data to be sorted by pinYin if the user inputs English, and sorted by the characters themselves when the user inputs Chinese characters.

Is there something like

```
if (searchText isKindofClass: UTF-8String)
```

to detect if an `NSString` contains Chinese characters?

Comment: The type of string wouldn't change regardless of what characters you type in.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can use a `NSRegularExpression` to search for "character families" :

https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html

http://userguide.icu-project.org/strings/regexp

They give an example of `\p{script=cyrillic}`, I guess by searching a little you'll find something related to Chinese.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! I just used `"[^a-z]"` and checked if `numberOfMatches` returned greater than zero.

Comment: That's a workaround, but it'll match `I am 29` when it shouldn't.

Comment: use `\p{script=Han}` with `NSRegularExpression`

Comment: Thanks for this answer. Would you kindly provide an example of how to do so? I looked into Apple documentation on `NSRegularExpression` but didn't see anything like a `isKindofClass: \p{script=Han}`- thanks!

Answer (score 2):

If you use `\p{script=Han}` to detecting Chinese, be sure to add '`\`' before `\p`. So it is like

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\\\p{Script=Han}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:&error];
```