# Example of using NSRegularExpression to detect if string contains Cyrillic

Tags: ios, iphone, regex, nsstring, nsregularexpression

I looked into the [Apple reference](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Foundation/Reference/NSRegularExpression_Class/Reference/Reference.html) on `NSRegularExpression`, and understand that in order see if the string is Cyrillic I should use `\p{script=cyrillic}`. However, I have not been able to find an actual example of how this is done in the reference guide or in an [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11897531/detecting-if-nsstring-contains-chinese-characters) located in SO. What I would ideally like to achieve is:

```
if (string contains \p{script=cyrillic}){
    return YES;
    }
else {
    return NO;
    }
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe (I am an iOS programming newbie):

```
- (BOOL)containsCyrillic:(NSString*)str
{
    NSString* const pattern = @"\\p{script=cyrillic}+";
    NSRegularExpression* regex = [[NSRegularExpression alloc] initWithPattern:pattern
                                                                      options:0
                                                                        error:nil];
    NSRange range = NSMakeRange(0, [str length]);
    return [regex numberOfMatchesInString:str
                                  options:0
                                    range:range] > 0;
}
```

And then the usage (a category for `NSString` would probably be better?)

```
NSLog(@"hello: %hhd", [self containsCyrillic:@"hello"]);
NSLog(@"привет: %hhd", [self containsCyrillic:@"привет"]);
```