# Is it possible to detect Chinese Characters using Regex on NSString

Tags: ios, objective-c, regex, nsregularexpression

I would like to detect a Other language string (Non English) using regex .

My Current Regex expression looks like `[a-z,A-Z,0-9,ä,ö,ü,Ä,Ö,Ü,ß,_]` in iOS

Kindly Provide me your inputs on this

Comment: Maybe have a look at this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/22275994/example-of-using-nsregularexpression-to-detect-if-string-contains-cyrillic and this: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9576384/use-regular-expression-to-match-any-chinese-character-in-utf-8-encoding

Answer (score 0, accepted):

(\p{L}),(\w+),(\w),

Above Regex expressions are used to allow other languages to be detected on custom attributed link