# How to detect chinese characters in string

Tags: ios, localization, nsstring

I have an `NSString` that is returned from my server. Before displaying the string, I need to detect it whether contains Chinese characters.

I tried using ASCII and UTF16 or UTF8 but it returned true for all strings.

Is there a better solution?

Comment: Can you show the code you have tried?

Comment: @stevekohls sorry i was removed the code that i was test. now i tried to use the code NSString *a=@"我们"; NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\p{script=Han}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil]; if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:a options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [a length])] > 0) { NSLog(@"got chinse"); } else { NSLog(@"no chinese"); }  but it not working

Answer (score 2):

As described in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/11898220/834998), you can use an `NSRegularExpression` to search for `\p{script=Han}`:

```
NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\p{script=Han}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:string options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [string length])] > 0) {
    // string contains Chinese characters
}
```

This will check if *any* characters in the string match `\p{script=Han}`, which is the specifier for the Unicode range of Chinese characters.

Comment: i had try     NSString *a=@"我们";
        
        NSRegularExpression *regex = [NSRegularExpression regularExpressionWithPattern:@"\p{script=Han}" options:NSRegularExpressionCaseInsensitive error:nil];
        if ([regex numberOfMatchesInString:a options:0 range:NSMakeRange(0, [a length])] > 0) {
            NSLog(@"got chinse");
        }
        else
        {
            NSLog(@"no chinese");
            
        } but it not working. it still nslog no chinese to me